# .NET Core 3.1 WPF moving .xaml files to class library

Tags: wpf, .net-core

I'm migrating an old WPF project to .NET Core 3.1 and some of my .xaml views are not in the .exe assembly, they're in a class library.

Visual Studio doesn't recognize any of the WPF namespaces in the class library project, like these:

`using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;`

If I change the type of the project to .exe, it works, but it's really ugly in my opinion.

In AspNetCore when I have similar issues and need to access specific AspNetCore namespaces in a class library, I need to include this in the `.csproj`:

`<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Is there a similar `FrameworkReference` value for WPF projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project file, add an entry `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to your TargetFramework:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```